# In Drupal 7, how do I make a block visible on the user view page, but invisible on the user edit page?

Tags: drupal-7, hide, visibility, block

In Drupal 7, I have added a block to the Content region of the User page.  I did this by specifying

`user/*`

in the Visibility Settings -> Pages -> Show block on specific pages -> Only the listed pages setting.

However, because the wildcard accepts anything, now the block appears on the User's edit page.

Is there a single number wildcard, like

`user/%integer`

that I can use here so that the block only appears on the User view page?

How can I hide this block on the User edit page in Drupal 7?

Comment: I did not figure out how to remove blocks programmatically from the user edit view, but the Context module allows me to add a block to every user profile page.  I also had to remove the original "Only the listed page settings" for that block in order for this work.  I still want to know which hook to call to remove a Views block before it is rendered on the user edit page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try enable PHP filter module, so that you can enter php on Block visibility settings page. 
There you can check for argument like

```
<?php 
if(arg(0) == 'user' && arg(2) != 'edit' )
return true;
else 
return false 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

These days there is another alternative available ... ***which doesn't require the PHP filter to be enabled*** (which you should try to avoid whenever possible) ... Just use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) intercept the situation where someone uses an URL like `/user/*/edit` (replace `*` here with any allowed value for `uid`). If you're not familiar with how to do that with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), then have a look at my answer to the question "[How to make the permissions of a module more granular?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326)" (and pay attention to the regex-expression included in the sample rule I included there).